# LINQ over WCF Service (DomainService)

Tags: wcf, linq, ria, wcf-ria-services, domainservices

I have a simple DomainService:

```
[EnableClientAccess]
public class DomainService1 : IDomainService1
{
    [Query(IsComposable = true)]
    public IEnumerable<int> GetCollection(int from, int count)
    {
        const int max = 100000;
        int[] _collection;

        _collection = new int[max];

        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            _collection[i] = i;
        }

        return _collection.Skip(from).Take(count);
    }
}
```

On client side I have generated proxy: client

I need comose LINQ query on client side and perform it on server side and throught service return query result.

When I do:

```
var res1 = client.GetCollection(100, 20).Skip(5).Take(5);
```

than client.GetCollection(100, 20) in performed on server side and Skip(5) and Take(5)
on client side.

When i do:

```
var res2 = client.GetCollection(100, 90000).Skip(10).Take(10);
```

it throw exception:

The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

I think that this is due, that client.GetCollection(100, 90000) return large resultset.

Is a way get better information about reason why server fault?
And it possible perform query from client on server? I think so, because this allows LinqToEntitiesDomainService. But i cannot use EF, because i have access only to list of object stroed in memory.

Thank you.

JPo

Comment: I dont see where you are composing the query on the client side.

Comment: leppie, it's when he appends .Skip(10).Take(10) after the GetCollection() call. If he was returning an IQueryable instead of IEnumerable it should enable that portion to occur on the server.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is almost certainly due to the large dataset, so you can try upping the maximum buffer/message sizes in the <binding> config, eg:

```
<binding name="MyServiceBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="6291456" maxBufferSize="6291456">
    <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="6291456" maxStringContentLength="6291456"/>
</binding>
```

Make sure you add those to the bindings in both the *client* and the *server*'s config.

As for getting the additional client-defined parts of the query to execute on the server, you might need to make the return value an IQueryable<int> instead.